# How to factory reset a Canon ImageCLASS printer?

Tags: factory-defaults, multi-function-printer

Giving an old Canon MF8580CDW printer to someone else. I want to do a factory reset so that they can easily set up the printer.

I've read other forums, but can't seem to find an answer. Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

These references might help (from [Factory reset for Canon MF8380C](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/198760-canon-mf8380-factory-reset) ):

> This was really hard, but I solved it after a bit of frustration...
>
> Press  "menu 2 8 menu"  (menu is the head with the star, above no. 1 key)
>
> Go to menu "COPIER->FUNCTION->CLEAR->ALL". Turn off the printer and on again. You will need to do all the settings again.
>
> Maybe you can choose a specific item to reset, I was so frustrated so I cleared all ...  Hope this will help you. Good luck!

Also, there is the User Guide but there doesn't seem to be a universal single-action factory reset (look at pages 37, 54, 80):

[Canon ImageCLASS MF8580Cdw/MF8280Cw Basic Operation Guide](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300010789/01/MF8580Cdw_8280Cw_BASIC_en-us_R.pdf)

Hope that helps!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reset sequence.  Of note: this sequence also works on Image Class MF8280Cw.

Comment: Sometimes logic is replicated on various models of a given class of printers, i.e. "ImageCLASS".  So, front panel functions might be the same, functionally, if not identical visually/symbolically.   However, the device limits for sizes etc may NOT be correctly set, so drivers may not always work ... but they are ALWAYS worth a try, fi there is nothing else.